# Several Software Serial Ports

Tags: serial, softwareserial

I am planning to use an Arduino (Nano ideally, or Other) to send and receive information from several software serial ports to other arduinos, over their available pins, ideally 8 ports.

I could understand an Asynchrounous Communication having one *master* and 8 *slaves*, with the master enabling communication from one port, receiving the data from that port, and then move onto the next port, into a sampling loop.

The `SoftwareSerial` library allows to set up the pins individually, and set the `listen()` port (thanks Juraj).

I read the `AltSoftSerial` library handle [some of the limitations](https://1sheeld.com/arduinos-softwareserial-vs-altsoftserial-library-use-1sheeld/) of the `SoftwareSerial` library, but I just realized the pins cannot be configured (without... cloning the full library?).

Question is:

- Option 1: Should I stick with the `SoftwareSerial` library?,
- Option 2: Should I try the `AltSoftSerial` library, and figure how to duplicate it (i think this is a NO)?
- Option 3: Understand that none of these libraries are prepared for this, and seek for other alternative?
- Option 4: It is pointless to have several serial trunks in Arduino, if only one will work at a time, and should hence try to arrange just one serial trunk?

Comment: you must set which instance should listen with `listen()`. only one can listen

Comment: You might be better off with an rs485 multi-drop bus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to use MIDI (which is quite slow: 31,250 bps), and that didn't work reliable with the software serial on the Arduino Uno. Since I wanted multiple ports, I switched to the Arduino Mega which has FOUR harware serial ports. I would suggest this above using so many software serial ports; it also will relieve your processor to use hardware serials.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a part with 2 hardware serial ports (Atmega1284P), and use a simple mux chip to switch between the slaves for the master to receive from, such as DG406
https://www.digikey.com/products/en/integrated-circuits-ics/interface-analog-switches-multiplexers-demultiplexers/747?k=dg406&k=&pkeyword=dg406&sv=0&pv1989=0&pv433=170&sf=0&quantity=&ColumnSort=0&page=1&stock=1&pageSize=25

Hardware serial will allow for faster comm's too, vs software serial.
1284P is Arduino friendly too.